# Set different default browser for different apps on macOS

Tags: macos, web-browser

My default browser is set to Edge but I would like that when I open links from apps like Outlook for example they, and only they, will open in Chrome.
Is there a way to manage this setting per app?

Answer (score 3):

I have looked for a solution to this several times in the past and just found three different options today. I'm going to list them in the order I recommend them, as I am sure there are reasons you may prefer one over the other.

[Velja](https://sindresorhus.com/velja) - Free, Mac App Store
Velja is free and is the app I am currently using to solve this problem. It lets you create rules to open links from specific apps in a specific browser, links to specific websites in a specific browser, and links to specific services in their respective app (Discord, Zoom, Music, etc.). It can also remove tracking parameters from links on open and holding the Fn key allows you to change the default behavior of a clicked link (I use it to let it prompt me for which browser I want to use to open the link I just clicked). It can even open links directly into a specific profile in your browser of choice, if your browser supports profiles. Due to the price of free and all the features I needed, this is my go-to recommendation. There is also a non-App Store version that is not automatically updated. A new version is only posted once a year, so I recommend the App Store version.

[Choosy](https://choosy.app/) - $10, Direct Download
Choosy is the inspiration for Velja. It is $10, but has a generous 45-day free trial and has virtually identical features. The place where Choosy stands above Velja is that it is that it lets you customize a list of browsers as your favorites (this includes profiles in Edge, Chrome, Brave, etc.). It also has much more robust rules, with a design similar to advanced Spotlight searches or Automator workflows. Rules run in order or priority, which means you can greatly customize what links open where. You can even configure rules to only trigger if more than one browser is open. When requesting a prompt for a browser to open, you can customize the appearance of the popover. If Velja is lacking a feature you'd like to see, Choosy is the way to go. And you can test it for several weeks before purchasing. Unfortunately, no App Store version for those users that like to keep their Gatekeeper settings locked down, but it comes from a registered developer, so no issues installing.

[Finicky](https://github.com/johnste/finicky) - Free, Open Source, GitHub
Finicky is not being actively developed, but is a very lightweight and open source solution. However, it does require you to either have some JavaScript knowledge or feel comfortable mucking about in code to figure out how to customize it. There is a [web tool](https://finicky-kickstart.vercel.app/) that will build a config for you, though. It only supports opening a specific browser based on websites, though. If you're trying to make sure that specific work apps only open links in a specific work browser/profile, this won't be the solution for you.

I hope one of these helps you like they did me!